# How should I create state using $stateProvider according to folder structure in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I am using `$stateProvider` for routing. Here is my folder structure

```
app
  -css
    -style.css
  -js
    -app.js
views
  -home.html
  -list.html
index.html
```

Here is my state code

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider.state('home',{
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl:'home.html',
    controller:'home'
})
});
```

But home page is not seen when application is loaded. If I use inline template and add HTML code of home.html in index.html it's working like

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
 // home.html code here--
</script>
```

How should I create state for this folder structure? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making a small mistake.
templateUrl inside $stateProvider should contain the full path of view from root directory.
It should be

```
templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
```

Kindly check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
its best advised to follow a folder structure by feature as below.

    app
     -module1
        -module1.home.html
        -module1.home.controller.js
        -feature1
           -module1.feature1.html
           -module1.feature1.controller.js
    -module2
        -module2.home.html
        -module2.home.controller.js
        -feature1
           -module2.feature1.html
           -module2.feature1.controller.js
    index.html  
sample stateprovider configuration as below.
here home is an abstract state which can be only invoked via its sub states.
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "<div ui-view></div>"
           })
        .state('home.module1', {
                 url: "/module1home",
                 templateUrl: "app/module1/module1.home.html",
                 controller: 'Module1HomeController'

             })

             .state('home.module2', {
                 url: "/module2home",
                 templateUrl: "app/module2/module2.home.html",
                 controller: 'Module2HomeController'

             });
```